# interactive plots and zooming in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, plotly, lsa

i am using the following code to plot an LSA of some document.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 15]

svd = TruncatedSVD()
Z = svd.fit_transform(X)
plt.scatter(Z[:,0], Z[:,1])
for i in range(D):
    plt.annotate(s=index_word_map[i], xy=(Z[i,0], Z[i,1]))
plt.show()
```

Now, the figure is cramped at the origin and i  want to zoom in to see what is going on around that point. Any ideas how to do so using matplotlib?
Any ideas on what could be a good replacement to plotly and cufflinks as they are not working anymore (plotly requires a subscription)

Comment: To zoom in use `plt.xlim(x0, x1)` and `plt.ylim(y0, y1)`

Comment: Do you mind to add a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: thanks for the tip. i will try that. but i am now trying to use plotly instead. i found out i can still use it. Thanks.